# Html code syntax error -

Tags: html, vb.net

My html code includes syntax error.

CompanyName is variable.

Any idea for this error?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like *just* HTML.  Is this a Windows Form?  What is this notation?  I've never seen HTML and .NET code mixed in this manner.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer to include an alternative solution.

Comment: My second solution is **LITERALLY** as simple as you'll get it! You just have to call `.Replace(string1, string2).Replace(string3, string4).Replace(...` and so on to replace multiple variables, _**or** use a For-loop._

Comment: There is pretty much no simpler way than to use proper quotation and line-breaking _or_ replace the vars in a saved string (i.e. `My.Resources`). Like David and the others have already told you, VB.NET doesn't support the kind of syntax that you're trying to use.

Comment: What about this ? https://support.microsoft.com/tr-tr/kb/976112

Comment: Amazingly that worked. I wrote `<%=CompanyName %>`. Well I was wrong then - there is one simpler way. But if things break you'll know the reason. But in general, that is not native VB.NET code so use it with caution.

Comment: Yeah.. That works for me too :-) So, this question is solved! Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work you have got to format the HTML String in a correct way, that means use proper quotation and line breaks.

```
.htmlbody = _
"<html>" & Environment.NewLine & _
"    <body>" & Environment.NewLine & _
"        <table width=""700"" border=""1"" align=""left"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"">" & Environment.NewLine & _
"            <tr>" & Environment.NewLine & _
"                <td width=""700"" bgcolor=""Red"" style=""text-align:justify"" valign=""center"">" & Environment.NewLine & _
"                    Dear, " & CompanyName & "<br></br>" & Environment.NewLine & _
"                </td>" & Environment.NewLine & _
"            </tr>" & Environment.NewLine & _
"        </table>" & Environment.NewLine & _
"    </body>" & Environment.NewLine & _
"</html>"
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you **really** do not want to use proper quotation this is probably as close as you get to what you want to achieve.

1. Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer and press `Properties` (fig. 1).
2. Go to the `Resources` tab, press the drop down menu and select `Strings` (fig. 2).
3. Create a new string, name it of your choice and then paste your HTML code in the `Value` field. Insert the text `[COMPANY]` or something similar where you want the company's name to be displayed (fig. 3).
4. Go back into the code, and when you're gonna use the HTML you refer to the string's name in `My.Resources`.

   Then you just call `.Replace()` on that string with the first parameter set to what you put instead of the company name in the HTML code, and the second parameter set to the `CompanyName` variable.

   ```
    .htmlbody = My.Resources.HTML.Replace("[COMPANY]", CompanyName)
   ```

Hope this helps!

---

### Fig. 1

[image: Project Properties]

### Fig. 2

[image: String resources]

### Fig. 3

[image: HTML String resource]

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to use a lot of double-quotes, because my code is already very long... I need simple code...

Comment: @Dr.Code : Still it's pretty much the only way you can achieve this! But okay, give me a few min to update my answer, there's one more thing you can try.

Comment: @Dr.Code: Then design a language which allows you to write code the way you want to write it.  As long as you're using an existing language, you have to follow the syntax of that language.

Answer (score 2):

Your strings are missing their quotes.

Instead of this:

```
.HtmlBody = <html>...</html>
```

Do this:

```
.HtmlBody = "<html>...</html>"
```

Raw HTML by itself isn't part of VB.  It's just a string.  Strings need to be surrounded by double-quotes in VB.

Once you do that, you can concatenate variables into that string using the `&` operator:

```
.HtmlBody = "<html>..." & someVariable & "...</html>"
```

Comment: Your advice is good but this is not answer of my question... But thanks anyway...

Comment: @Dr.Code: In what way is the question not answered?  Can you explain what errors you are receiving with this suggestion applied?

Comment: I need a solution without strings need to be surrounded by double-quotes in VB...

Comment: @Dr.Code : There's no other way than surrounding the strings with quotes. Check my answer, it's probably as close as you'll get.

Comment: @Dr.Code: Unless there's some way to do that in VB with which I'm unfamiliar (and you don't seem to have found one either), then what you're asking is for something that the language itself doesn't support.  Good luck with that.  Is there any particular reason *why* you don't want to quote your strings?

Comment: @David. I'm assuming it's because just wrapping the quotes on the beginning and ends of the tags are wreaking havoc on the strings that are embedded in the actual string itself. (ie, <table width = `"700"`. Those will need to be fixed with `<table width = ""700""` to denote that you still want the quotes inside the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to show special characters on web page you write **HTML entities** like ampersand(&), greater/less than symbol(<,>) or any other special characters.

Here is the link for all HTML entities. 
https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

```
<html>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td> &amp; Campny Name &amp; </td>
    </tr>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He wants to display the value of the variable _CompanyName_ not the string CompanyName between & symbols

Comment: OK but according to the question he just want to say there is an syntax error in HTML, picture also shows it

Answer (score 0):

You are using [XML literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx) syntax to define your HTML.  You can [embed expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384752.aspx) into XML literals using the `<%= varName %>` syntax, so your code should look like:

```
.htmlbody =
    <html>
        <body>
            <table ...>
                <tr>
                    <td ...>
                        Dear <%= CompanyName %> <br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>.ToString()
```

The XML literal defines an [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), unless you include an XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`), in which case it will be an [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb341005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call will pretty print the XML, although there is an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb551415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allows you to override that.

Comment: @VisualVincent Not really, the link the OP provided was to a page about Web Forms, from what I could tell (don't know what language it was in), and while the syntax is the same, it does explain why it works in this case. Also, comments aren't a substitute for answers,and may be cleaned up in the future.

Comment: @Dr.Code White space between XML elements is ignored, so to put a space between embedded variable values, concatenate them both in a single embedded expression, with the space included, e.g. `<%= CompanyName & " " & RichTextBox306.Text %>`.  You could also use a separate embedded expression with the space, if that works better for the particular situation, e.g. `<%= CompanyName %><%= " " %><%= RichTextBox306.Text %>`.

Comment: @Dr.Code Please ask new questions in the future, but as the error says, you can't put an expression inside a quoted attribute value, so you need to use `<td width... style=<%= "background-color: " & ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Button301,BackColor) & ";" %>>`.